# I'm getting a NameError even though the called function is already in my class

Tags: python

I have a class called **Stream** that has multiple functions in it. A function called **live** is called inside another function in the same class **Stream** but doing so prints the **name live is not defined** error.

```
class Stream(Thread):

   def __init__(self):
      # declare some stuff

   def live(x, y):
      # do something

   def run(self):
      # do something
      var = live(a, b)
      # do something
```

When running this file, I get the NameError error.

Comment: `live` is an attribute of `Stream`, not a variable in any scope that `Stream.run` can see. `class` statements do not create a new scope.

Comment: so how would i use live in this situation? I actually need whatever live returns for **run**

Comment: The same way you would any other class attribute: `vat = Stream.live(a, b)`. Note that since it neither expects nor receives `self` as an argument, it should probably declared as a static method. (Or defined outside the class altogether, in which case you *can* use `live` as an ordinary global variable.)